# How to match quantifiers { 6, } in RewriteRules?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I did a rewrite rule matching document names that are 6 characters, and it succeeds.

```
RewriteRule ^document\/(.{6})\/?$ document/?name=$1 [NE,L]
```

Since I know documents are named only up to 12 characters, I added a maximum length quantifier. However, using this, it produces a 500 Server Error:

```
RewriteRule ^document\/(.{6,12})\/?$ document/?name=$1 [NE,L]
```

In fact, I'm getting the following results:

`(.{6})` works
`(.{6,})` faults
`(.{6,7})` works
`(.{6,8})` works
`(.{6,9})` faults
and so on.

I should also mention that https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=109235 tells me there isn't anything wrong with my rule. However I'm still getting the 500 Server Error on use.

Thank you @emma, example URLs to be rewritten:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/document/051201-22
>
> http://www.mywebsite.com/document/051201-22/

Comment: What happens when you try `[^\/]{6,12}` ?

Comment: I don't think that regexpal tests rewrite rules

Comment: If I were you, I'd remove the BOS anchor `^` from your regex since it's not going to match `http://www.websited.com/` that is in front of 'document'. Even if that part get's stripped off, you should take the caret out of the regex.

Comment: @sln ([^\/]{6}) works, ([^\/]{6,12}) faults

Comment: The question is does it support range quantifiers `{n,m}`. It either does or doesn't, there is no it works on some ranges but not others, that's not possible. Since I don't feel like learning all this just to answer a question, I'm going to give you a way to use a range without the range. Requires look ahead assertions, but that should fault as well right ? Here, try this  `document/(?=.{6})(?!.{13})(.+)/?$`

Comment: In fact, it supports SOME, but not all: (.{6,8}) works (.{6,9}) faults

Comment: @sln .. again, it doesn't seem to like 2-digit ranges. In your example, document/(?=.{6})(?!.{13})(.+)/?$ (faults), but: document/(?=.{6})(?!.{9})(.+)/?$ (works).

Comment: You know Ben, at least you're getting closer to finding out why it is the engine you're using is so f**ed up, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you'd like to write this RewriteRule. However, [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/JukTzT/1) might help you to first find an expression, then write and test a RewriteRule. I'm pretty sure, you can write it without using a quantifier. For example:

```
document\/([0-9]+)
```

would pass your exampled URLs.

Then, if you wish to only replace the first six digits to the name variable, you might want to write a RewriteRule similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mywebsite\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule document\/([0-9]+) document\/?name=$1 [NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

For yes or no trailing slashes, these might work:

```
# No Trailing Slash Policy, if you wish no slash at the end of your URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

# Trailing Slash Policy, if you wish to have a slash at the end of your URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/ [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping I could qualify the request, before the rewrite, for between 6 and 12 characters. That way I could use another rewrite rule to send them to an instructions page (or failure page), if the URL didn't contain a valid document name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you enter in a redirect loop with this setup.
Add a `RewritCond` to check that there is not a query string in the request

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
>
> RewriteRule ^document/([^/]{6,12})/?$ document?name=$1 [NE,L]